# Django inbuilt password_reset view not sending email

Tags: django, email

I am using the django inbuilt urls and views for the auth process.

I am trying to use django's inbuilt urls and views for the user authentication but have customized the html files, e.g. login.html registration/password_reset_form.html

I have imported the urls in my url.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import urls
```

and in the urlpatterns

```
url(r'^account/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

in my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import *
```

(with no other view functions to handle the auth process)

Now the after entering the valid email address for sending the email in the `password_reset_form.html`, the page is redirected to `password_reset_done.html`, but I could not receive email

Below is the setting for email in my settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
    EMAIL_PORT = 25
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

And when I try the django quick example of sending email

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['mymail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

it shows the error message of `error: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

So this mean I have to do something before the django inbuilt password_reset could send the email. anyone could help explain what else I am supposed to do to get the sending email function working?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your settings, a local smtp server should be installed on your machine (or your server depending where you are making your example run)

Try with your GMAIL (or YAHOO or whatever provider you are using) to be sure of your settings.

If you are a sendmail user, sendmail being a mail server usually used on unix machines, you could use this [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1864/) to implement a custom mail backend. The declaration of the custom backend is done through the EMAIL_BACKEND setting parameter in your setting file.